# Must Apache virtual hosts be used when developing on localhost?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

My document root is the default `/var/www/html`. If I create some subdirectories inside the `html/` directory:

```
html/
    example/
    dev/
    test/
```

I seem to have many *sites* that I can access in my web browser:

```
localhost/example
localhost/dev
localhost/test
```

Considering the above, setting up Apache virtual hosts seems unnecessary. Should I use Apache virtual hosts when developing on localhost? Please say why in any answers you provide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't see a need for it, you don't need it. I like to be able to have seperated cookie storage areas, host-absolute links that start with "/", different site icons in the browser,  the ability to use /etc/hosts to point real-life domain names to localhost, etc

Comment: Thanks @Thilo for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use virtual hosts for development because it prevents unintended cross contamination (i.e. using an image etc that belongs on another site).

But that is just my opinion.

Also it separates the work up better.